# Javascript with XSL

Tags: javascript, xml, twitter-bootstrap, xslt

I'm trying to make dropdown using `Bootstrap` framework. This is how I did:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just like in example. And this is how I include `.js` in `xsl`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.js">&#160;</script>
```

So the menu doesn't work. I see few buttons, but no dropdown effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also include jQuery and bootstrap css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Don't forget to include jQuery BEFORE bootstrap js.